# EF6 Migration automatic Migration is not executed

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

Hi I'm trying my hands on a EF6 Code First approach. I understand the basic Concept of Migration and how Code First works but somehow this does not work. I wrote the following Migration class myself not via Add-Migration:

```
public override void Up()
{
  CreateTable("dbo.Todo", column => new 
  {
    Id = column.Int(nullable:false, identity:true),
    Value = column.String(nullable: true),
    CreatedAt = column.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETUTCDATE()")
  }).PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
}

public override void Down()
{
  DropTable("dbo.Todo");
}
```

But the up Method is not called My Configuration class is as follows:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DataProviderCodeFirst.Entities.TodoContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
        ContextKey = nameof(TodoContext);
    }

    protected override void Seed(DataProviderCodeFirst.Entities.TodoContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

This is my DataContext:

```
public TodoContext(): base("SomeConnectionString")
{

}

public TodoContext(string connectionString)
  : base(connectionString)
{
  Database.CreateIfNotExists();
  Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TodoContext, Configuration>());
  Database.Initialize(false);
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}


public virtual DbSet<Todo> Todos { get; set; }
```

An my Entity Class

```
  public class Todo
  {


    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public string Value { get; set; }

  }
```

It creates the Database and the tables the key is set to identity, but the CreatedAt is not set to computed and in Debugging the Up() Function is not called.

Thanks is advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to run 'Enable-Migration' then 'Add-Migration' command and then run  'Update-Database' command.